# Realtime update of multiple Highchart React graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, electron, react-hooks

**EDIT 1:** Thanks to [ppotaczek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8951377/ppotaczek) it seems that the problem comes from the Chromium engine as the problem does not manifest on Firefox.

**Some context**

I'm currently working on a monitoring application for Energy systems (involves heavy duty batteries and inverters). The application communicates via CAN bus with a voltage sensor on the system.

The goal is to display in realtime the voltage value of multiple cells of battery (it can vary from 13 to a 100).

We are using a Python back-end hooked to an electron app that runs React 
(Since it's a new app 90% of the code uses React Hooks).

**THE PROBLEM**

We are currently facing an issue caused by the rerender of each of the chart every seconds.
It causes the entire application to suffer from micro freeze exactly at the time of the rerender.

*We think the re-render is the culprit because disabling it makes the app smooth even though we keep all the communication layer running*

GIF Video : https://i.imgur.com/zRVRWHQ.mp4

**THE CODE**

Right now the data are collected in the Python backend and formated as such :

```
batteryData = {
"ts": 0,
"cells": [
    {'index': 0, 'voltage': 0}
],
"temperatures": [
    {'index': 0, 'temp': 0}
],
"stackTemperatures": {
    "temperatureMin": 0,
    "temperatureMax": 0,
    "temperatureAvg": 0
},
"boardTemperatures": {
    "temperatureMin": 0,
    "temperatureMax": 0,
    "temperatureAvg": 0
},
"current": 0.0,
"soc": 0.0,
"soh": 0.0
```

}

It's sent every second to the Electron app via socketIO.
Currently each of the graph listen to an IPC event that sends the data as soon as the electron receives the Data from the Python backend :

**ELECTRON IPC**

```
ipc.on('page-loaded', () => {
console.log('received can data : ' + data)
win.webContents.send('can-data', data)
})
```

**REACT IPC**

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.ipcRenderer.send('page-loaded', "loaded")
    window.ipcRenderer.on('can-data', (event, arg) => {
      setTableState({tableData: JSON.parse(arg)})
    })

}, []);
```

Then the Graph widget goes on and retrieve the "Cells" Data from the tableState object (usually 13 cells for 13 different voltages value each seconds)

**DATA FORMATTING**

```
const updateSerie = () => {

        if (tableState && tableState.tableData) {
            if (!voltagesInit) {
                tableState.tableData['cells'].map((cell, index) => {
                    if (voltagesSerie.length != tableState.tableData['cells'].length) {
                        voltagesSerie.push({
                            name: 'voltage ' + index,
                            data: [cell.voltage],
                            type: 'spline',
                            dataType: 'voltage',
                        })
                    }
                })
                setVoltagesInit(true)
                chartOptions.series.push(...voltagesSerie)

            }
            else {
                var offset = 0
                chartOptions.series.map((serie, index) => {
                    if (serie.data.length > 300)
                    {
                        serie.data.shift()
                    }

                    switch (serie.dataType) {
                        case 'voltage':
                            serie.data.push(tableState.tableData['cells'][index - offset].voltage)
                            break;
                        default:
                            offset += 1
                            break
                    }
                })
            }
             setChartOptions({
                series: chartOptions.series
            })  

        }
```

**Things we already tried :**

- Collecting the DATA in the graph component parent once and distributing it via props to avoid collecting the same data multiple time (a bit worse than now because the container has to re render every seconds)
- Using highchart class component instead of hooks to use the addPoint method as they showcase (Even worse results)
- Collecting the Data inside the widget component (current situation see GIF) to avoid the container rerender.

Comment: Hi @Guillaume Collet, Did you try to use the `boost` module? I have created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4765/ which I think is very similar to your case and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, indeed your implementation would be what i'm looking for. However i'm not able to wrap my mind around how to translate this into a react component. 

The lifecycle constraint in React are making this process tedious. 

Also I wonder if the rendering can be impacted by electron (as opposed to google chrome ) 

Thanks I'll investigate in the mean time on how to implement this

Comment: please check this example with React: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-qkghl

Comment: Hey Thanks, I've checked this example. And if you try to scroll (without using the mousewheel) you'll witness the same problem as i have on the Gif

Comment: Ah, It seems that the boost module is not working. Please check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-wendm

Comment: Still the same :( GIF : https://imgur.com/a/YCV1BBx

Comment: It looks that is a problem only in Chrome browser. I tested that example in Firefox and it works ok. You have a lot of JS calculations (60 new points per second) and this is the main issue.

Comment: Hooo Gosh you are right. and Since electron runs on chromium it makes sense that the problem is happening here too. 
I'll go an search on this thanks for the guidance tho :)

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek I doubt that the calculation are that heavy. I've tried disabling the rendering of the graph. (but kept the calculation running in the background) and there is no performance issue there. 
Have I understood your point correctly ?

Comment: I meant Highcharts calculations in `addPoint` and also `redraw` method. But I think that you are right - this is more a Chrome problem, maybe you should report a bug on chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list ?

Comment: Ok @ppotaczek I've reported the issue on the link you provided https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1049951 as well as on Highchart's forum https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=43294

On a second note I've observed a similar problem with Plotly.